# Is it possible for photons to have different energy and same momenta if they are emitted by bichromatic light source in all directions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

Suppose photons are emitted by a bichomatics source of light in all directions. Is it possible that two photons are present having different energy but same momenta ?

Comment: Hi, in the title you are asking about photons having different energy but the same momentum, while in the text you asked about two photons having different momenta but the same energy. Can you clarify?

Comment: It is different energy and same momenta.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter the source, all photons have a simple relationship between their energy and momentum:

$$p = \frac Ec$$

So in any frame where two photons have the same energy, they also have the same magnitude for their momenta and vice versa.

Comment: Consider the direction as well. I found in a book that a bichromatic source of light emitting in all direction.Here few photons having different energy and same momenta are possible. Note: i am not talking of same energy , different momenta but the oppsite as different energy and same momenta.

Comment: As I mentioned, the source is irrelevant.  If the momentum magnitude is the same, the energy is the same.

Answer (score 1):

No,the energy of any (real) particle (not just photons) is uniquely determined by its 3-momentum according to the [mass shell condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell):
$$E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + \vec p^2c^2}$$
Since all photons have the same mass ($m_\gamma=0$), any photons with the same 3-momentum $\vec p$ will have the same energy $E=\lvert\vec p\rvert c$.